# Could not stop the wampapache service on Local Computer

Tags: apache, service, wampserver, windows-server-2003

Sometimes the applications running on the WAMP server are not responding.

Then, I restart the services:

- wampmysqld
- wampapache

Usually, it fixes the problem, but sometimes the **wampapache** service cannot be stopped. When I try to stop it (right click > Stop) from services.msc, it shows:

> **Could not stop the wampapache service** on Local Computer.
>   Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

[image: Could not stop wampapache]

Trying to stop it from command line doesn't work.

If I restart the machine and I run the following commands:

```
START wampserver.exe 
NET START wampapache
NET START wampmysqld
```

then everything works fine.

How can I restart the wampapache service without restarting the whole machine?

**Details:**

- Windows Server 2003
- WAMP5 Version 1.6.6

  - MySQL 5.0.27
  - Apache 2.0.59
  - PHP 5.2.0

Comment: Can I ask what `launch_wampserver.bat` is please. And **WAMP5** wow that is **well old** Probably about as old as Windows Server 2003. What versions of Apache/MySQL and PHP came with that

Comment: I added the details to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar problem. To stop the "hanging" service you can kill the process of httpd.exe (Apache).